# Which ICs can I use to amplify electrical signals from plants?

Tags: botany, biotechnology, electrophysiology

I wanted to record variation potential and action potential generated in plants due to some stimulus. So which are the ICs that I can use for the amplifying the signals and what kind of experimental setup would be best. I was thinking of using Ag/AgCl microelectrodes with 0.1M KCl solution for measuring the electrical impulses in tomato plants.